# Why jquery date picker plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm making todo web application. If i run only date picker code it will run but when I combine with other html code it doesn't work

It only displays

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--datepicker-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/todolist/datepicker.css") }}">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="datepicker">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script href=" {{ asset('/js/todolist/datepicker.js') }}"}}></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
                autoHide: true,
                zIndex: 2048,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click on input field field it should display date.

Comment: Is this bootstrap date picker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the error console?

Comment: no jquery plugin

Comment: which one ? there are thousands! => https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=datepicker&type=Repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains syntax error - use `src` to import datepicker plugin.

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/todolist/datepicker.js') }}"}}></script>
```

Here you can find workable example of your plugin (I used CDN instead of GitHub),

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    zIndex: 2048,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fengyuanchen/datepicker@0.6.5/dist/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fengyuanchen/datepicker@0.6.5/dist/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<div clas="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrectly importing the `datepicker.js` script. It should be `src` not `href`. It is also possible that you might have some errors in the syntax for your templating language, but I'm not sure what you're using so I can't be 100% confident about that. I think it needs to be like this,

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/todolist/datepicker.js')}}"></script>
```

But definitely it needs to be `src` and not `href`. If I reproduce your code and substitute the Github pages script from that repository, it works fine.

```
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Definitely don't use the Github pages URL though--it shouldn't be used as a CDN. I'm just using it as an example that proves that your problem is with the way you're importing that script.